# Show that $M(f * g) \leq (M f) * (M g)$ for all $f, g \in L^1(R)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, functional-inequalities

Let $f \in L^1 (R)$. By $M f$ be the restricted maximal function defined by

$$(M f )(x) = \sup_{0 <t<1} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f(z)| dz.$$
Show that $M(f * g) \leq (M f) * (M g)$ for all $f, g \in L^1(R)$

**My Proof**

\begin{align}
M(f * g)(x) &= \sup_{0<t<1} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{B(x,t)} |(f*g)(z)| dz\\
&= \sup_{0<t<1} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{B(x,t)} \left|\int_\mathbb{R} f(z-y)g(y) dy\right| dz\\
&\leq \int |g(y)| \left( \frac{1}{2t} \int_{B(x,t)} |f(z-y)|dz\right)dy\\
&\leq \int |g(y)| Mf(x-y)dy=(Mf*g)(x)\\
\end{align}

Similarly, we have

$$M(f * g)(x) \leq (f*Mg)(x).$$

**Edit**

We consider $M (M(f*g)) \leq M(Mf * g)$, and the right side becomes

\begin{align}
M (Mf * g)(x) &= \sup_{0<t<1} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{B(x,t)} \left| \int Mf(y) g(x-y) dy \right| dx\\
& \leq \int |Mf(y)| \left( \sup_{0<t<1} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{B(x-y,t)} |g(x-2y)|dx \right) dy\\
& \leq 2 \int |Mf(2y) Mg(x-2y)| dy\\
&= (Mf * Mg)(x)
\end{align}

Comment: You have to repeat the argument to finish the proof.

Comment: Are you able to use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: @geetha290krm You mean the argument to finish the second inequality?

Comment: If I'm interpreting geetha290krm's comment correctly, you would need to use $M(f \ast g) \leq M(M(f\ast g))$ (I wouldn't be surprised if they were equal).  As for mine, if you can use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, one simple corollary is $|g| \leq Mg$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Is it a known result?

Comment: Are you asking whether the Lebesgue differentiation theorem is a known result? If so, then yes.  If you're asking whether its corollary is a known result, then almost certainly, but it's basically true by "look at the definitions: the limit as $t\to 0^+$ is at most the supremum over $t \in (0,1)$."